# Running a SQL install script with SMO. Alternative solutions needed

Tags: sql-server, scripting, installation, smo

I've got a web application that uses Microsoft Sql Management Objects (SMO) dll's. I'm wondering how I go about redistributing the libraries for a remote machine.

As I understand it, these come with SQL server or Sql express - which isn't on the remote (shared) webserver. Asking the host to install them, is probably out of the question, so is it possible to dynamically load them?

See below error-

Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo, Version=9.0.242.0,   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Alternatively, if anyone can provide a workaround for the below snippet that would also be useful. The script variable is a SQL install script which has been read to the end. The nice thing about this is the outputting of each of the execute strings from SQL. I could of course just execute it all in one chunk, but that provides no visual feedback to the user line by line, that the sql is executing ok.

Is there a stored procedure that could perform this sort of thing? Or an alternative way to execute an install script without full permissions.

```
           Dim connection As New SqlConnection(Me.ConnectionString)

            connection.Open()
            connection.Close()

            Dim server As New Server(New ServerConnection(connection))
            server.ConnectionContext.SqlExecutionModes = SqlExecutionModes.ExecuteAndCaptureSql
            Dim commands As StringCollection = server.ConnectionContext.CapturedSql.Text
            server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(script, ExecutionTypes.ContinueOnError)





            Dim s As String
            For Each s In server.ConnectionContext.CapturedSql.Text
                AppendMessages(s)
            Next
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.mattberther.com/2005/04/11/executing-a-sql-script-using-adonet/

from

http://coolthingoftheday.blogspot.com/2006/11/execute-t-sql-scripts-with-gos.html

Was what I was looking for, and did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

you can try using [sqlcmd utilty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) that comes with sql server

Comment: Think that still requires admin access..this is for a shared hosting environment.

Comment: then look into the database publishing wizard:
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=56E5B1C5-BF17-42E0-A410-371A838E570A&displaylang=en

Comment: Needs to be a standalone solution, executed by a non techie user from a web application. So that is out too. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't dynamically load them, and no, you can't install them without permissions.  Sorry about that, but no dice there.